# What are the differences between ++= and += in sbt, say with libraryDependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to Scala and sbt and I can't understand what the differences are between:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)
```

and

```
libraryDependencies += ...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is `+= dep` or `++= Seq(dep, dep2, dep3)`: ["Of course, you can also use ++= to add a list of (read: multiple) dependencies all at once"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html).

See [collections.Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) for the `+` ("append *an item*") and `++` ("append *a sequence*") operators.

Answer (score 8):

See [Appending to previous values: += and ++=](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/More-About-Settings.html#Appending+to+previous+values%3A++and):

> Assignment with `:=`is the simplest transformation, but keys have other methods as well. If the `T` in `SettingKey[T]` is a sequence, i.e. the key’s value type is a sequence, you can append to the sequence rather than replacing it.
>
> - `+=` will append a single element to the sequence.
> - `++=` will concatenate another sequence.
>
> For example, the key `sourceDirectories in Compile` has a `Seq[File]` as its value.

Answer (score 3):

One way to strip this down to a simpler problem is to look at the two parts in separation.

First, there's the `...=` part. You're probably familiar with this syntax from Java and other languages, but it performs the `...` operator on both the left and right operands, and stores it back into the left operand - in this case, it stores it back into libraryDependencies.

Second, there's the choice of either `++` or `+`. If you take a look at the [Seq Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) then you'll find these two operators. The difference here is that:

1. `+` takes a single element on the left-hand side, and prepends it to a sequence, returning a new sequence as the result.
2. `++` takes a sequence on the left and a sequence on the right and returns a new sequence of both.

In practice, this means that you will get different results from the two.

- `List(1, 2, 3) ++ List(4, 5, 6)` will return `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, but...
- `List(1, 2, 3) + List(4, 5, 6)` will return `List(List(1, 2, 3), 4, 5, 6)`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, things you write in `sbt.build` is also in the Scala syntax. So this is essentially a question about Scala itself and not limited to SBT.

Generally speaking, in Scala:

- The `+=` function in a mutable collection (like `ArrayBuffer[T]`) means to append a single element to the collection. The type of this function's parameter is `T`, the type of the element.
- The `++=` function, which is also found in a mutable collection, means to append all elements of another collection to the collection you call `++=` on. The type of this function's parameter is `TraversableOnce[T]`, which many of Scala's collection types (like `Seq[T]`) extends.

#### Example

So, say if you have an `ArrayBuffer[Int]` like the one below:

```
val testSeq = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If you write

```
testSeq += 5
```

`testSeq` will now become `ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Or if you write the following *instead*

```
testSeq += Seq(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

`testSeq` will now become `ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`.

#### Wrong Example

If you say

```
testSeq ++= 5
```

You'll see a compilation error, because `++=` accepts a collection rather than a single element. If you really want to append a single element by `++=`, you should write:

```
testSeq ++= Seq(5)
```

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator adds the `Seq` given as argument to the end of the other `Seq`.

`+` adds a single element to the front of the `Seq`.

The `=` after the `+` and `++` indicates that the left hand `Seq` is a `var` and will be updated.

Documentation for Seq is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq).